# Does Power Stone Statue increase probability to get prototype modules?

Tags: boom-beach

I was wondering if a purple statue **Power Stone** could increase our luck to get some prototype modules for the weapon lab ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is no.

The purple Power Stone statue only increases the probability of receiving Power Stone's not prototype modules.

There is an 8% chance you will gain a prototype module by completing one of the following :

- Destroying Mercenary Bases
- Destroying Blackguard Bases
- Destroying Dr. Terror Bases
- Winning the Hammerman Strikes Back events
- or by Achieving Reward Thresholds in Colonel
  Gearheart events

However you must first construct a Weapons lab before you can collect prototype modules. The only exception to this rule is the War Factory event.

This 8% chance can **not** be increased in anyway.... as yet.

Comment: Ok, then, no way to increse this luck ?

Comment: Nope, afraid not. I've amended my answer to give you a bit more detail.

Comment: Thank you :)
I know  there's 8% chance :/
I can't defeat these guys, I'm level 37, very hard to do this :O